# How to determine whether DOS console will be closed after the program terminates

Tags: .net, console-application

When I run my console application it displays some output, which I want the user to see. In addition, my program has to be run in elevated mode.

So when a user runs it from a non-elevated command prompt, the standard dialog is presented where the user accepts running it elevated. The problem is that a new console window is created for that and closed immediately after the program terminates. I want it stay to let the user read the output.

Simple, right? Just add `Console.ReadLine()` at the end of the code. But then, when run from an elevated prompt, no new console is created, yet the user will have to press a key to let the application exit — annoying.

My question: Is it possible to know that the console window will be closed as the app terminates, so that I can do the `Console.ReadLine()` only then?

Thanks.

Comment: This presumably the same sort of situation would also arise if a user ran your application by right-clicking it in Explorer and choosing "Run as administrator." So it's not just when a new console is created from another console, there's that path as well. Mentioning it because the runtime environment will be slightly different (the console won't have another console as its parent environment).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need some minor pinvoke to discover this.  The GetConsoleProcessList() api function returns a list of processes attached to the console.  That will be more than 1 if your program inherited the console from another process.  Make it look similar to this:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace ConsoleApplication1 {
    class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            if (OwnsConsole()) {
                Console.Write("Press ENTER to exit");
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
        public static bool OwnsConsole() {
            int[] pids = new int[1];   // NOTE: intentionally too short
            int retval = GetConsoleProcessList(pids, pids.Length);
            if (retval == 0) throw new System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception();
            return retval == 1;
        }
        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern int GetConsoleProcessList(int[] pids, int arraySize);

    }
}
```